# DropDown Scrolls up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get my dropdown menu box so that if i click outside it it will scroll up. I am using the code below to do just that. But for some reason when i click it it just scrolls on up for no reason. You can see a demo here of what i mean. http://bit.ly/sIvM2I To see an example click see our newfeed.

And this is the jfiddle im using http://jsfiddle.net/zBkxj/6/ To see an example click see our newfeed.

Why is it just scrolling up when i click it on http://bit.ly/sIvM2I ? What is wrong with my javascript? To see an example click see our newfeed.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#bottom').click(function() {
    $('#content').slideDown();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id !='bottom') {
        $('#content').slideUp();
    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works as you expected

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bottom').click(function() {
        $('#content').slideDown();
         event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('html').click(function(e) {
        //alert(1);
        if (e.target.id != 'bottom') {
            $('#content').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

try the live demo at [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamranali/zBkxj/16/)

Comment: Oh i see what it is. What about if i want to click on see our news feed again how can i get it to scroll up with that too?

Comment: Same thing happens as before.